# DenseMatrix invalid assignment

Tags: f#, mathnet-numerics

Not sure how to populate a DenseMatrix type:

```
let rows = [|for line in File.ReadAllLines("Z:\\mypath.csv") 
            |> Seq.skip 1 do yield line.Split(',') |> Array.map float|]
let data = DenseMatrix.ofRowArrays rows
let mutable data_logdiff = DenseMatrix.zero<float> (data.RowCount-1) (data.ColumnCount)

for i in [0 .. data.ColumnCount-1] do
    for j in [1 .. data.RowCount-1] do
        data_logdiff.At(j-1, i) <- data.At(j, i) / data.At(j-1, i) |> log
```

The last line generates an error "invalid assignment".

Would also like to know if there is a functional way to express the logic above.

Thanks.

Comment: Don't assume everybody knows which library are you using and which namespaces have you opened, include them in the code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will assume you are using MathNet, don't know which version.

First of all, I don't think your `data_logdiff` needs to be mutable, it's already an object with properties which you can mutate, I mean you want to mutate its properties, not the object itself.

Then the problem in your code is how you mutate those property, you should use an indexer instead of `.At` which will return only the value:

```
#r @"packages\MathNet.Numerics.3.8.0\lib\net40\MathNet.Numerics.dll"
#r @"packages\MathNet.Numerics.FSharp.3.8.0\lib\net40\MathNet.Numerics.FSharp.dll"

open System.IO
open MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra

let rows = [|for line in File.ReadAllLines("Z:\\mypath.csv") 
        |> Seq.skip 1 do yield line.Split(',') |> Array.map float|]
let data = DenseMatrix.ofRowArrays rows
let data_logdiff = DenseMatrix.zero<float> (data.RowCount-1) (data.ColumnCount)

for i in [0 .. data.ColumnCount-1] do
    for j in [1 .. data.RowCount-1] do
        data_logdiff.[j-1, i] <- data.At(j, i) / data.At(j-1, i) |> log
```

To make it more functional use `DenseMatrix.init` instead of `DenseMatrix.zero` and then looping:

```
let data_logdiff = 
    DenseMatrix.init 
        (data.RowCount-1) 
        (data.ColumnCount) 
        (fun j i -> if j = 0 then 0. else data.At(j, i) / data.At(j-1, i) |> log)
```

Generally speaking everytime you use `.zero` and a loop to initialize a matrix or a vector consider using the `.init` function instead, that takes an additional parameter which is the something like the body of the loop.

Comment: Very slick. Thanks.